# NumPy - Insert an array of zeros after specified indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code is:

```
x=np.linspace(1,5,5)

a=np.insert(x,np.arange(1,5,1),np.zeros(3))
```

The output I want is:

```
[1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,5]
```

The error I get is:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be
>   broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,)

When I do:

```
x=np.linspace(1,5,5)

a=np.insert(x,np.arange(1,5,1),0)
```

The out is:

```
array([1., 0., 2., 0., 3., 0., 4., 0., 5.])
```

Why it doesn't work when I try to insert an array?

P.S. I I cannot use loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
np.hstack((x[:,None], np.zeros((5,3)))).flatten()[:-3]
```

gives:

```
array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  5.])
```

That is, pretend `x` is a column vector and stack a 5x3 block of zeros to the right of it and then flatten.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to feed repeated indices. For a 1d array, thhe `obj` argument for [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) reference individual indices.

```
x = np.linspace(1, 5, 5)

a = np.insert(x, np.repeat(np.arange(1, 5, 1), 3), 0)

array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  5.])
```